Not proud of work, should I allow submission?
One of the students in a research group I worked with years ago has picked up my old work and is trying to get it published, but I am not proud of the quality of work. The paper is based on a manuscript I wrote many years ago, and despite updates made by the student, it is clunky writing. Even with feedback on the writing style, I do not see the work as a useful contribution in hindsight. The paper has already been rejected from other venues on multiple occasions.
The student is in the process of resubmitting the paper to yet another venue. Should I let them resubmit the paper? I am worried about future collaborators judging my research abilities based on this not-amazing publication since I would be listed as an author. However, I do not want to be seen as a hurdle to collaboration by turning down publication or forfeiting authorship. How does one approach this kind of situation?
Edits in response to comments:

I worked on the core content of the paper and wrote the original manuscript years ago. The student then reorganized sections and added some new text. My original manuscript was written as a young undergrad without much experience, so the writing, even back then, wasn't great. I have given feedback on the writing style of the revised paper. It isn't awful, just not stellar.
I am currently outside academia but interested in applying to graduate programs soon.
It is not wrong work, just meh.



What is your contribution to the paper? Just feedback on the writing style? 2. What is your current work situation? Are you a postdoc somewhere else? Tenured or tenure track? Outside academia? This information may affect the answers.


Is it wrong or just meh work?

@FedericoPoloni I have updated my post to answer these questions

@JonCuster just meh work, not wrong.

Put yourself in their shoes - they are trying to learn still. Help them. Good karma and all that. Nobody will think worse of you.


I do not want to be seen as a hurdle to collaboration by turning down publication or forfeiting authorship.

Given the situation you described, I recommend you rethink the option of forfeiting authorship.  Obviously the student is keen on the paper even though you are not, and if left to your own devices, it would remain unpublished anyway (with no authorship credit).  You don't owe the student your collaboration on the paper, and gifting the student your previous draft as a starting point is already giving them a leg-up.  An advantage of forfeiting authorship and leaving the student to work on their own is that it takes the entire matter out of your hands and gives the student the opportunity to learn about the difficulties of publication of work on their own.

+1 Mature experience in this answer.

Haha, perhaps somewhat of a back-handed compliment to attribute mature experience in producing work I'm not proud of.  ;)

Respect only.
